# C++ not writing whole data to UART port

Tags: c++, wiringpi

I have been testing UART communication in C++ with wiringPi.

**The problem:**

It seems that C++ isn't outputting whole data into the UART port `/dev/ttyAMA0`. Perhaps I'm doing it the wrong way?

**Investigations**:

*Note : I am using **minicom**, `minicom --baudrate 57600 --noinit --displayhex --device /dev/ttyAMA0` to check the received data.*

**Also!** The UART port, **RX** & **TX** pins are shorted together.

The python code worked perfectly however when I tried to implement it in C++, the data received is different.

**The expected received data should be: `ef 01 ff ff ff ff 01 00 07 13 00 00 00 00 00 1b`.**

##### Received Data Comparison:

| Language Used | Data Received from Minicom |
| --- | --- |
| Python | ef 01 ff ff ff ff 01 00 07 13 00 00 00 00 00 1b |
| C++ | ef 01 ff ff ff ff 01 |

**Code used**

Python:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

packet = [239, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255, 1, 0, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27]

uart.write(bytearray(packet))
```

C++:

Note: Code compiled with `g++ -Wall -O3 -o test hello.cpp -lwiringPi`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

      int serial_port;

      if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
            exit(1);

      if ((serial_port = serialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA0", 57600)) < 0)
      {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
      }

      cout << "Sending data to UART" << std::endl;

      serialPuts(serial_port, "\xef\x01\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x07\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b");

      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `serialPuts` to send the null terminator. As with all similar functions, it will stop when the null terminator is encountered in the string.  In this case I think your best option is to add a function that uses the ordinary `write` function that is used internally by WiringPi's own functions.

You could make a wrapper function to make it look similar to the other calls:

```
#include <cstddef>

void serialWrite(const int fd, const char* data, size_t length) {
    write(fd, data, length);
}
```

and perhaps a function template to not have to count the length of the data in the fixed data arrays manually:

```
template<size_t N>
void serialWrite(const int fd, const char(&data)[N], bool strip_last = true) {
    serialWrite(fd, data, N - strip_last);
}
```

You can now use it like so:

```
serialWrite(serial_port, "\xef\x01\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x07\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b");
```

Note: There is a [pull request](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/pull/72/commits/434451c5cff415f0f9f68899369b090ed2dbd82d) to add a similar function (called `serialPut`) to the WiringPi library that you could download instead of using the official version from the master branch version if you don't want to make your own function.

Comment: That did the trick! It took me awhile to recompile the entire library though. Thank you so much!